# How to solve concurrent read + write update to the document in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb

I have an application that runs multiple instances and that needs to perform this:

1. Read the document
2. Check a value of the timestamp field
3. If an incoming document is newer, then update (including the timestamp field).

Even if I use transactions, two parallel operations would be able to perform 1 and 2 simultaneously and then both will write to the database, potentially writing the "older" document last (since it will check the timestamp of the original document, rather than a "new" one)

So what I am looking for is some kind of a read lock on the document or some other mechanism that will be able to solve this.

Comment: All updates are atomic on document level, please read https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/core/write-operations-atomicity/ and may be https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/faq/concurrency/ to understand locking strategy

Comment: It is not just the update that needs to be atomic in my case, I cannot update if I read stale data first. Thanks for the reference, I tried to understand the document, but did not seem to find the answer to my question in there

Comment: The $inc operator does the atomic update serverside. There is no need to read stale data. I understand this is a made up example which doesn't help you, so I  suggest to update the question with something that is more aligned with your usecase.

Comment: Good point, I thought it would be easier with this made up example, but I have updated it to be a one that I am trying to perform

Comment: Sorry Ilya, I probably wasn't clear enough. Mongo has quite comprehensive language for atomic updates. $inc operator is the simplest case. There are no read-for-write locks by design. They opted to atomic updates instead, so if you provide the details (an example document and what you are trying to to read, update on application level, and replace), people might give you an idea how to write it in mongo syntax.